# issue in making call in android 4.4 throws ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

"Am new to android development, help out with the solution, for am not able to make call in android 4.4. Am getting ActivityNotFoundException when i try to click the button. I have provided here with my java class and manifest file"

```
**JAVA CLASS:**
package com.example.phone_call;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Button b1;
   //String phone = "0000000000";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
     // call();


       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             //phone = editphone.getText().toString();      
            call();
        }
    });

   }


   private void call() {
   Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
      in.setData(Uri.parse("+91 9488873581"));
     //startActivity(in);
       try{
         startActivity(in);
      }

      catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not a valid number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

 }

**MANIFEST FILE:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.phone_call"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.phone_call.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: someone help me out wit the solution to make a call

Comment: thnkx fr the info.. I missed out "tel:" in (Uri.parse("+91 9488873581"))
dat was d mistake i got it.. 
it shld be (Uri.parse(" tel:+91 9488873581"))